# How to make UITableViewCell adjust height to fit its content?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to make a `UITableViewCell` like below, which will adjust its height according to its content view. The image in the center should be as wide as the cell frame, and adjust its height proportionally.

[image]

As you can see, the image in the cell doesn't display like the way I want. I tried to set the height of the `UIImageView` to 320.0 in `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`, but doesn't help at all.

Question: how can I make the cell to respect the height of image?

FYI:

1. I'm not overriding `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat`
2. I don't set a height constraint to the `UIImageView` or anything, I'm using paddings only to arrange views.
3. The image is display using *aspect-fit* mode.

**Edit:**

I moved further to add a height constraint to picture:

```
class MyTableViewPostCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var contentLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pictureImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pictureImageViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
}

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyTableViewPostCell") as MyTableViewPostCell
        cell.contentLabel.text = "This is a very very very very very very very long content."
        cell.pictureImageViewHeightConstraint.constant = 320
        cell.pictureImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://somedomain.com/pic"))
        return cell
    }
}
```

And I got a constraint conflict error when running. See below:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff7b5026c30 V:[UIImageView:0x7ff7b50289e0(40)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff7b5029a90 V:[UIImageView:0x7ff7b5029990(320)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff7b502a630 UIImageView:0x7ff7b50289e0.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff7b5028910.topMargin + 6>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff7b502a770 V:[UIImageView:0x7ff7b50289e0]-(12)-[UILabel:0x7ff7b5029390'This is a very very very ...']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff7b502a950 V:[UILabel:0x7ff7b5029390'This is a very very very ...']-(10)-[UIImageView:0x7ff7b5029990]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff7b502aa40 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff7b5028910.bottomMargin == UILabel:0x7ff7b5029c20'Label'.bottom + 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff7b502aa90 V:[UIImageView:0x7ff7b5029990]-(17)-[UILabel:0x7ff7b5029c20'Label']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff7b2cae430 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ff7b5028910(283.5)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff7b5029a90 V:[UIImageView:0x7ff7b5029990(320)]>
```

I don't know where `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` comes from, but seems like it is causing the conflict. Any way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: See this post: [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Answer (score 7):

**For iOS 7 and below**

Use AutoLayout and add constraints properly, then use the `UITableViewCellHeightForRow` method for dynamic height.

**For iOS 8 and above**

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```